# Tomcat HawtIO JMX over Jolokia authorization

Tags: security, authorization, jmx, hawtio, jolokia

this is my situation:

1) I have an web application, that is running on **Tomcat**, inside my war I have bundled Jolokia, so now if I do something:port/jolokia I get JSON back and all works well.

2) I downloaded executable jar from **howt.io** and I start it from cmd (on windows) and it gets running on some defined port so I get nice web page from which I connect to my server and read JSON from Jolokia, I can see some mbeans from JMX and it's all good!

3)Now here comes the problem, I have spring-security so I configure that **/jolokia/*** is protected with some role, **ADMIN** for example, now how can I connect from **Howtio** to my server ? I guess I should somehow provide user/pass and get session token back or something, I have no idea where to go from here so I would appreciate very much your help!

I came up with the solution to deploy Howtio as war to my server, and then I enable authentication hawtio.authenticationEnabled=true and set tomcat users, all works well but I would really like to just have jolokia there because I have many instances of my application (on more than 50 servers), so I would like to use Howtio just as a client that will read JSON, but I need some way of securing all that!

So please if someone have an idea or can tell me how to do this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found a solution for this, the problem was browser basic authentication!

Read more about it here -> [link](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2215#issuecomment-259330121)

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to remote jolokia instances is done via the 'Connect' tab.  You can save connections in there to your tomcat instances, including providing a username and password, for example:

[image: screenshot of JVM connect page]
Note: this page may have been updated a bit since this screenshot.